# Tool to plot color ramp/palette on saturation vs brightness grid

Tags: software-recommendation, color-theory

Are there any tools that help plot colors on a saturation vs brightness grid like below? (And perhaps even help adjust the colors)

I've seen this used on a couple different sites, but they seem to be custom jobs:

- https://uxplanet.org/designing-systematic-colors-b5d2605b15c
- https://design.gs.com/foundation/color-system/creating-the-system

My goals:

- create a nice color palette/color ramp that includes a specific color like this [blue](https://oklch.com/#45.503,0.3109778330818,265,100)
- analyze other color palettes like

  - https://picocss.com/docs/colors
  - https://github.com/fchristant/colar
  - https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/

[image]

[image]

**Update:** Specific reasons for wanting to visualize colors on a grid like this:

- Ensure enough contrast
- Smooth curves on this grid seem more aesthetic. Here is an example where the resulting curve seems to help explain why this combination of reds seems "off" and disjointed:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can I ask what is your ultimate goal here? Is it just to create a colour ramp with adequate contrast? While the graph is a nice visualisation,  HSB/HSV values should be enough to build a nice colour ramp. Creating something like this that works interactively would involve coding (not on topic for GDSE) or just doing it manually. Also I think trying to find what, if any, software tool already exists for this would be like trying to find a needle in a haystack that may or may not actually exist.

Comment: @BillyKerr I updated my question with more specific goals and reasons for wanting the visualization. I found this type of plot in different places, so it seemed like a common practice that might have a tool to help automate it. My background is in software development, so if there is no such tool, I can create a small web app myself and post it as an answer ^^